# Impossible to publish CodePlexProject, No "publish" button available

Tags: codeplex

I have started a codeplex project, which right now does not have source code. I would like to publish the project so it could be visible, but nowhere can I find the publish button.

Instead, I only have a message saying `Your project will be removed on Dec 3, 2013, if still unpublished.` and a button for deleting my project.

I have seen projects with no source code being published on CodePlex, so I am at a loss as to what is wrong. I have chosen a license, and updated the Main page with description and all, but I have been unable to publish it.

Any help would be more than welcome.

Cheers.